# How to save the state of multiple column checkboxes and update them all on one click button

Tags: c#

I have been able to create grid view consisting of multiple column check. I am developing the web application and  I am not able to save the state of the multiple column check and update them all on one click button.

Comment: Show code please.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve your problem.
 sol 1)

```
List<bool> list = new List<bool>();
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkboxid")).Checked)
   {
         list.Add(chkboxid.Checked);
   }            
   else
   {
     list.Add(chkboxid.Checked);
   }
}
```

and then do what you want to do with this list

and another method is if you want to send this checkbox states to the database then create a datatable in CS page and save your checkbox state in it and send the datatable to the database for you refernce [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412802/Sending-a-DataTable-to-a-Stored-Procedure)